# How to slice a row with duplicate column names and stack that rows in order

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-science, google-colaboratory

[image]

I have a dataframe as shown in the image and I want to convert it into multiple rows without changing the order.

```
  RESP HR SPO2 PULSE
1  46  122  0    0   
2  46  122  0    0   
3
4
```

Comment: Can you add expcted output from sample data, also 3 row? Do you need repeat `RESP` value from last previous column in new Dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is use [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), only necessary modulo of length of columns is `0` (so is possible convert all data to 4 columns `DataFrame`):

```
df1 = pd.Dataframe(df.values.reshape(-1, 4), columns=['RESP','HR','SPO2','PULSE'])
df1['RESP1'] = df['RESP'].shift(-1)
```

General data solution:

```
a = '46 122 0 0 46 122 0 0 45 122 0 0 45 122 0'.split()
df = pd.DataFrame([a]).astype(int)
print (df)
    0    1  2  3   4    5  6  7   8    9  10  11  12   13  14
0  46  122  0  0  46  122  0  0  45  122   0   0  45  122   0

#flatten values
a = df.values.ravel()
#number of new columns
N = 4
#array filled by NaNs for possible add NaNs to end of last row
arr = np.full(((len(a) - 1)//N + 1)*N, np.nan)
#fill array by flatten values
arr[:len(a)] = a
#reshape to new DataFrame (last value is NaN)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(arr.reshape((-1, N)), columns=['RESP','HR','SPO2','PULSE'])
#new column with shifting first col
df1['RESP1'] = df1['RESP'].shift(-1)
print(df1)
   RESP     HR  SPO2  PULSE  RESP1
0  46.0  122.0   0.0    0.0   46.0
1  46.0  122.0   0.0    0.0   45.0
2  45.0  122.0   0.0    0.0   45.0
3  45.0  122.0   0.0    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Iam getting this error : ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2348 into shape (5)

Comment: @NajamShah - if check modulo `2348 % 5 = 3` so it means last 3 values has to be removed for working. Or need add missing values to end like last row should by `data, data, data, NaN, NaN`?

Comment: @jezrael would this even give the correct results if not the above error? For instance, this won't re-use the RESP column from row 1 as the first column of row 2 and everything then gets one column out of order going onwards...

Comment: @JonClements - You are right, seems more complicated

Comment: sorry my mistake I dont want to repeat the RESP again

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way with `groupby`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.arange(12), columns=list('abcd'*3))

new_df = pd.concat((x.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
                     .rename(k) for k,x in df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1)), 
                    axis=1)

new_df = (new_df.assign(a1=lambda x: x['a'].shift(-1))
                .rename(columns={'a1':'a'})
         )
```

Output:

```
   a  b   c   d    a
0  0  1   2   3  4.0
1  4  5   6   7  8.0
2  8  9  10  11  NaN
```

Comment: yop, maybe double `a` column should be explain - rather not, because selecting problems