# parsing text into pandas using regular expressions, but empty dataframe produced

Tags: python, regex, pandas, parsing

I am trying to parse the following data into pandas from a text file:

```
genome Bacteroidetes_4
reference B650
source carotenoid

genome Desulfovibrio_3
reference B123
source Polyketide
reference B839
source flexirubin
```

I'd like the output to like like this:

```
genome,reference,source
Bacteroidetes_4,B650,carotenoid
Desulfovibrio_3,B123,Polyketide
Desulfovibrio_3,B839,flexirubin
```

I have adapted some code (https://www.vipinajayakumar.com/parsing-text-with-python/ by Vipin Ajayakumar)

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# write regular expressions
rx_dict = {
    'genome': re.compile(r'genome (?P<genome>.*)\n'),
    'source': re.compile(r'source (?P<source>.*)\n'),
    'reference': re.compile(r'reference (?P<reference>.*)\n'),
}

# line parser
def parse_line(line):
    for key, rx in rx_dict.items():
        match = rx.search(line)
        if match:
            return key, match
    # if there are no matches
    return None, None
```

I believe there is a problem in the file parser, somewhere in the while loop.

```
def parse_file(filepath):    
    data = []  
    # open the file and read through it line by line
    with open(filepath, 'r') as file_object:        
        lines = file_object.readline()        
        for line in lines:           
            # at each line check for a match with a regex
            key, match = parse_line(line)

            # extract from each line
            if key == 'genome':
                genome = match.group('genome')
            if key == 'Source':
                Source = match.group('Source')               
            if key == 'reference':
                Type = match.group('reference')

                while line.strip():
                    row = {
                        'genome': genome,
                        'reference': reference,
                        'Source': Source,
                        }
                    data.append(row)
        data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return data
```

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    filepath = '/path/file.txt'
    data = parse_file(filepath)
    data.to_csv('output.csv', sep=',', index=False)
```

When I run this code it returns an empty dataframe:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Any tips for how to correct this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the parse_file function needs some logical correction.

Changes are like:

1. case sensitive 'Source' vs 'source'
2. moved data.append(row)
3. readline() vs readlines(), read line will read one line ; so "for loop" was looping on characters which was not the intend here.

```
def parse_file(filepath):    
    data = []  
    # open the file and read through it line by line
    with open(filepath, 'r') as file_object:        
        lines = file_object.readlines() # change 1        
        for line in lines:   
            # at each line check for a match with a regex
            key, match = parse_line(line)

            # extract from each line
            if key == 'genome':
                genome = match.group('genome')
            if key == 'source':
                Source = match.group('source') # 4 typo, s need to be small letter.
                #while line.strip(): Change 3, code moved after source, and while loop commented.
                row = {
                    'genome': genome,
                    'reference': reference,
                    'source': Source, # change 5, s to be small in the header
                    }
                data.append(row)
            if key == 'reference':
                reference = match.group('reference') # change 2
                
        data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return data
```

output:

```
genome,reference,Source
Bacteroidetes_4,B650,carotenoid
Desulfovibrio_3,B123,Polyketide
Desulfovibrio_3,B839,flexirubin
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't quite get there, however I think you can avoid regex.

I edited your original data to be as follows (NB the addition of genome Desulfovibrio_3 three lines from the bottom) and added it to a text file. I can't think of a nice way to do this addition programmatically. You can of course loop through the file line by line and where you don't find a 'genome' right before a 'source', add in the 'most recent' one - I'll leave this to you.

```
reference B650
source carotenoid

genome Desulfovibrio_3
reference B123
source Polyketide
genome Desulfovibrio_3
reference B839
source flexirubin
```

You can then use pandas to read said file as follows:

```
data = pd.read_csv('./sample_data.txt', sep=" ", header='infer', names=['data']).T
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data.values.reshape(-1, 3), columns=['genome','reference','source'])
df1.to_csv('./output.csv', index=False)
```

Source for the second line: [How to slice a row with duplicate column names and stack that rows in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59105439/how-to-slice-a-row-with-duplicate-column-names-and-stack-that-rows-in-order)

Output:

```
genome,reference,source
Bacteroidetes_4,B650,carotenoid
Desulfovibrio_3,B123,Polyketide
Desulfovibrio_3,B839,flexirubin
```

Comment: It seems like a great alternative because its so much shorter. I think I could try " df.fillna(method=ffil) " to fill in the first col. Thanks for adding this!